# java exit app causes infinite loop

Tags: java, android

i have made a simple java app to print a text file then should terminate. 
I tried to use the return statemend but didn't work at all. So i used the system.exit(0) but instead of exit the app, it goes in an infinite loop...
this is my code: can someone tell me what is wrong ?

```
package com.example.testprinterdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

import com.pda3505.Service.CaptureService;
import com.pda3505.printer.PrinterClassSerialPort;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static PrinterClassSerialPort printerClass = null;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();

        printerClass.write(new byte[] { 0x1d, 0x21,0x00,0x00});
        printerClass.write(new byte[] { 0x1b, 0x26, 0x00 });


        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/mnt/sdcard/temp.txt"));} 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        String line = null;
        try {line = reader.readLine();} 
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        while(line!=null) {
            printerClass.printText(line);
            printerClass.printText("\n");
            try {line = reader.readLine();} 
            catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
        system.exit(0);
    }


    private void init() {       

        printerClass = new PrinterClassSerialPort(new Handler());
        printerClass.open(this);

        Intent newIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CaptureService.class);
        newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startService(newIntent);

    }

}
```

Comment: Debug your program please. It will occur to you.

Comment: Yeah I agree with @f1sh, it is obviously coming from your while loop, so you should be able to debug and find the problem.

Comment: Try including your while loop inside the try clause which throws IOException. `try { while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { .. } } catch { ... }`. For exiting, try using `finish()` before `exit(0)`.

Comment: line.readLine() never returns null, see my answer for more info

Comment: Great !!! using 
finish();
System.exit(0);
it works :))))) thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
    try{
        //never hard code the file path in Android.
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"temp.txt";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        while (true){
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if(line.length() > 0){
                printerClass.printText(line);
                printerClass.printText("\n");
            }else{
                break;
                //you can use return too
            }
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In your approach, line is never null, it is either `""` or it is `" "` or `"\n"` etc, but never null. so listen for length and break the loop

> Please avoid multiple try catch blocks when you can have your code under single try block. And please scope the variables properly, do not declare variables outside the scope where it is not used, as it causes problems for JAVA Garbage collector/